# MongoDB REST interface "not allowed" with authentication

Tags: mongodb, rest, authentication

Using mongodb v.3.0.3, the REST interface stopped to work after setup the authorization with keyFile.

Now, the message is *"not allowed"* using the REST interface http://10.10.10.1:28017

Config file /etc/mongodb.conf:

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
dbpath = /data/mongodb
fork = true
httpinterface = true
keyFile = /etc/mongodb.key
logappend = true
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
nojournal = false
pidfilepath = /var/run/mongodb/mongodb.pid
port = 27017
replSet = mongodb
rest = true
smallfiles = false
```

There is some way to get REST interface working again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's built-in (and limited) REST interface does not support the new SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication as at MongoDB 3.0 (see: [Compatibility Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#http-status-interface-and-rest-api-compatibility)).

The REST interface is also disabled by default as it represents a security risk (see: [Security and MongoDB API interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#rest-api)); you definitely do not want this enabled in production environments.

There are [third party REST interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) available which provide a broader range of features and support.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

As a workaround
I made a small command line tool
https://github.com/sielaq/RSstatus

so you can have a human readable format like:

```
$ ./rsstatus.sh 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Member               |Id |Up |Votes |Priority |State             |optime
|mongo-ams1-001:27017 |0  |1  |1     |1        |SECONDARY         |592bd3d3
|mongo-ams1-002:27017 |1  |1  |1     |1        |PRIMARY           |592bd3d3
|mongo-ams2-001:27017 |2  |1  |1     |0        |SECONDARY         |592bd3d3
|mongo-ams2-002:27017 |3  |1  |0     |0        |SECONDARY(hidden) |592bd3d3
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```